# Swift Attack vs Full Attack

Tags: deathwatch

When a character with Swift Attack parries, then counterattacks, killing an opponent attacking with a Full Attack (getting two attacks), does the opponent's second attack still 'go off'?

A kroot with two attacks attacked our assault marine. He parried the first blow and counterattacked, killing the kroot. We didn't know if the kroot's second attack still went off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot depends on what the nature of the two attacks is.

If it's a simultaneous attack with two weapons, I'd have let the second happen, tho probably requiring an Ag roll to get it off before the counter attack landed.

If it's two attacks with the same weapon, I'd not have allowed a second attack.

But this is off the cuff, Old-School approach, not a rules-lawyer approach.